# Hibernate - cascading entities with oneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm not sure if I'm implementing properly a method responsible for inserting Product from user input. The main classes are:

**Product.java**

```
   public class Product {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
      private Long id;

      private String name;
      private BigDecimal price;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
      private Category category;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "producer_id")
      private Producer producer;
```

**Producer.java**

```
 public class Producer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
  private Country country;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "trade_id")
  private Trade trade;
}
```

Method for adding the product into DB:

```
  try {
      var product = ProductUtil.createProductFromUserInput();

      var category = OptionalHelper.of(categoryService
              .getCategoryByName(product.getCategory().getName()))
              .ifNotPresent(() ->
                      categoryService.addCategoryToDb(product.getCategory()).orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("Category is null")));

      var country = OptionalHelper.of(countryService
              .getCountryByName(product.getProducer().getCountry().getName()))
              .ifNotPresent(() ->
                      countryService.addCountryToDb(product.getProducer().getCountry()).orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("Country is null")));

      product.getProducer().setCountry(country);

      var trade = OptionalHelper.of(tradeService
              .getTradeByName(product.getProducer().getTrade().getName()))
              .ifNotPresent(() ->
                      tradeService.addTradeToDb(product.getProducer().getTrade()).orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("Trade is null")));

      product.getProducer().setTrade(trade);

      var producer = OptionalHelper.of(producerService
              .getProducerByNameAndTradeAndCountry(
                      product.getProducer().getName(), product.getProducer().getTrade(), product.getProducer().getCountry()))
              .ifNotPresent(() ->
                      producerService.addProducerToDb(product.getProducer()).orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("Producer is null")));


      product.setCategory(category);
      product.setProducer(producer);
      productService.addProductToDbFromUserInput(product);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info(e.getMessage());
      log.error(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
      throw new AppException(String.format("%s;%s: %s", PRODUCT, ERROR_WHILE_INSERTING, e.getMessage()));
    }
```

The thing is I can't do cascading while persisting producers, products and trades, because there are requirements about produces uniqueness by name, country, and trade, trade have to be unique by name, product has to be unique by name, category, and country, country have to be unique by name.\ etc.

In other words, if I'd make insert cascading there could be duplicated key error, so I had to check "manually" if there are countries, trades, products in the database already like in the above method. The question is, could I make it in another way, more in an "automatic way"?

Comment: As you don't seem to have the restrictions as constraints in your database, you need to ensure that all referenced entries are existing before you can create the connection between them

Comment: I don't think there is a way, it is not very common in most applications to create multiple records from a single input, so as far as I know, you'll have to live with this code :)

Comment: @XtremeBauer The thing is the method should be responsible for creating a "composite" elements like product in the above example if there's no such product in a db already

Comment: That's common code. What's your problem with it?

Comment: just wanted to ensure if there isn't other way around